# Modify group of JLabel elements in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to modify a `JLabel` after added it to the frame.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    JLabel newlabel = new JLabel();
    newlabel.setText("somekindoftext");
    newlabel.setBounds(50, 50+(10*i), 150, 14);
    newlabel.setVisible(true);
    object.add(newlabel);
}
```

After I added them to the frame, how can U modify them separately?

So if I have a function called `modifyText()` how can I reach the labels, modify the text, and after it redraw it to the panel?

Comment: You'll have to save the JLabels in an array, and access them that way.  Use a Swing layout manager, rather than positioning components yourself.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: What is `object`?

Comment: this code snipped is in a class, and I call it from the jFrame's onload event. and I gave the parameters through it. call: `someClass.someFunc(this)`  in the function: `public someFunc(Object object)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to add your labels to an `ArrayList<JLabel>`, that is a field of your class:

```
private ArrayList<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

...

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    JLabel newlabel = new JLabel();
    newlabel.setText("somekindoftext");
    newlabel.setBounds(50, 50+(10*i), 150, 14);
    newlabel.setVisible(true);
    object.add(newlabel);
    labels.add(newLabel); // <-----
}
```

Now you can refer to the labels as `labels.get(0)`, `labels.get(1)`, `labels.get(2)` etc.